# Bit shifting 16 bit from left to right C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have an array of 8 bit with the following representation.  `Data[i] = 192=11000000`, `data[i+1]= 85=01010101`, i need to transform the represenatation into 16bit array where `newArr[i] =343=101010111`.  The same numbers only shifted to right. My first idea was to use the field i have bpp (number of bits =10). So `var t=16-10`. `Data[i] >>t`. And `Data[i+1]>>t` however this doesn't give the correct answer.  Please help

Comment: Are you just storing number data in the arrays, shouldn't there be a cast from 8bit to 16bit

Comment: Right-shift usually sign-extends (though I believe that is dependent on hardware implementation). By not casting up first you enforce the sign-extension (when it occurs, as here). Just be thankful you discovered this in development, instead of after deployment.

Comment: To be clear: You want to 1) shift the bits to right and 2) convert the byte-array into a ushort-array?

Comment: Byte array into signed short array.  And shift it to the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have these two functions for you, to shift in a byte-array:

```
static public void ShiftLeft(this byte[] data, int count, bool rol)
{
    if ((count <0) || (count > 8))
        throw new ArgumentException("Count must between 0 and 8.");
    byte mask = (byte)(0xFF << (8 - count));
    int bits = rol ? data[0] & mask : 0;
    for (int i = data.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int b = data[i] & mask;
        data[i] = (byte)((data[i] << count) | (bits >> (8 - count)));
        bits = b;
    }
}

static public void ShiftRight(this byte[] data, int count, bool rol)
{
    if ((count <0) || (count > 8))
        throw new ArgumentException("Count must between 0 and 8.");
    byte mask = (byte)(0xFF >> (7 - count));
    int bits = rol ? data[data.Length - 1] & mask : 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        int b = data[i] & mask;
        data[i] = (byte)((data[i] >> count) | (bits << (8 - count)));
        bits = b;
    }
}
```

For your code example, call them like this:

```
byte[] data = ...;
ShiftLeft(data, 2, false);
```

Assuming you want to copy 2 bytes into 1 ushort, you can use this code (make sure it is even in length!):

```
byte[] data = ...;
short[] sdata = new short[data.Length / 2];
Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, sdata, 0, dataLen);
```

If you want to copy 1 byte into 1 ushort, then this would be the answer:

```
byte[] data = ...;
short[] sdata = Array.ConvertAll(data, b => (short)b);
```

Comment: `rol` means that bits which fall out on the left, are pushed in at the right (when you are shifting left of course).

Answer (score 1):

I take your question to mean you want to do this conversion: combine `aaaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbbb` into `bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaa` and then apply a right-shift by 6, yielding `000000bbbbbbbbaa`.

Then this will be your code:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    byte[] src = new byte[2] { 192, 85 };
    ushort[] tgt = new ushort[1];

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < src.Length ; i+=2 )
    {
      tgt[i] = (ushort)( ( src[i+1]<<8 | src[i] )>>6 );
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine( tgt[0].ToString() );
  }
}
```

If what you want to do is combine to `aaaabbbbbbbbaa`, then this will require `|`-ing a `src[i]<<10` in a second step, as there is no circular shift operator in C#.

Answer (score 0):

my final code :D

```
 public override short[] GetShortDataAlignedRight()
    {
        short[] ReturnArray = new short[_channels[0].Data.Length / 2];
        if (_channels[0].Bpp == 8)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(_channels[0].Data, 0, ReturnArray, 0, _channels[0].Data.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            short tempData;
            int offsetHigh = 8 - (16 - _channels[0].Bpp);
            int offsetLow = (16 - _channels[0].Bpp);
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < _channels[0].Data.Length; i += 2, j++)
            {
                tempData = (short)(_channels[0].Data[i] >> offsetLow);
                tempData |= (short)(_channels[0].Data[i + 1] << offsetHigh);
                ReturnArray[j] = tempData;
            }
        }
        return ReturnArray;
    }
```